# obtener pagos vencido en excel

Tags: excel, formulas

como obtengo el pago vencido con estos datos, usando cualquier formula en excel

```
grupo // saldo Bruto  //    Capital // Interes neto // IVA     // Pago Vencido
A       $4882877162    $1908754237   $2570628086     $403494838       ?
B       $348017637     $176000089    $147098437     $24919110         ?
C       $342091926     $157812551    $158876619     $25402755         ?
```

se debe de obtener mediante alguna formula en excel.

Comment: Debes de subir el código, o parte de lo que hayas intentado para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Esto quiere decir que el interés que muestras es anticipado?